# Multiple Scripts in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my manifest document I reference a script like this:

```
...
"background": {"scripts": ["Script.js"]},
...
```

Script.js uses chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener and redirectUrl and runs when users click a link or types in a website.

I would like to add another function that executes every 12 hours. This script will use chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener and chrome.alarms.create. It seems like I can't run these APIs on the same page as the ones above and will need another page, and that I need to make this script not persistent:

```
"background": {"scripts": ["Alarm.js"], "persistent": false},
```

How do I make Script.js and Alarm.js co-exist in the same extension and to make one persistent and the other not?

Comment: Why do you think you cannot use those apis in the same file, and that you need to use an temporary background?

Comment: I get a "failed to load extension from: ~\Desktop\Folder The 'webRequest' API cannot be used with event pages." error when its combined into one file and I try to make the page "persistent": "false".

Comment: Then simply don't use persistent: false?

Comment: Would that lead to any overhead issues? The alarm examples I'm coming across use persistent false.

Comment: The background page will be persistent. It won't unload automatically. What overhead? I'd say it's the other way around: a non-persistent event page adds overhead because it's loaded/parsed each time it's needed. Anyway extensions can't have two background pages.